# access a local server using internet address

Tags: apache, networking

I connected a raspberry in my home network:

- I can ssh to it over internet
- I can ssh to it from home as well, but only using local address

I would like to access it seamlessly no matter if I am at home or somewhere else (so I would always use the internet address).
For ssh I can type the right address according to the situation but for some other applications this is a problem. For example I have a "owncloud" client and it needs to always use the same address...

when I attempt to use the internet address from my local network, I get a time out error.

Is it coming from a setup issue in my home router or something on the pi ?? (apache2 is running on the pi)

more details about my router setup:

- static local address for the pi
- ports 443 (owncloud) and 22 (ssh) redirected to the pi

I do not necessarily want to keep this as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that to work out of the box a router supporting "loopback" is necessary.
If yours don't support it, then the next best thing is to turn on your VPN: since the VPN hides your IP as the sending IP, the router just see a normal request from a random IP.
It seems there are other tricks that can be done on the router, but the routers that don't support "loopback" are unlikely to give enough control for those tricks too...